# How do I solve this direct proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've been having a bit of trouble solving direct proofs, and I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction in solving this proof.

```
 If an integer d divides integer m, then d divides mn for any
 integer n.
```

I honestly have no idea how to start this problem even though I know it's pretty simple.

Comment: You don't "solve" a proof, you find one.

Comment: $d $ divides $m $ means $m=d\times something $.  $d $ divides $mn $ means $mn=d\times something $.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: what does it mean for one integer to divide another?

Answer (score 2):

If $d|m$ then $m=dk$ for some integer $k$. Multiply this by $n$ and you're pretty much done.